# How to make my laptop to use only a part of my diplay?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, dell-inspiron

I am using a Dell 1980 x 1080 Inspiron 5558, Windows 10 laptop. My laptop screen got damaged from the top and right side and so anything behind that portion of the display isn't visible as shown in the following picture:
[Broken Screen Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7GJL.jpg)

I want to limit my windows to use only part of the screen as shown in the following picture (the part in the orange rectangle) and leave the rest of the screen:
[Part of Screen I want windows to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuKR6.jpg)

Any suggestions on how can I do so or Any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is up to your monitor driver.
Right click your desktop
Choose "display setting"
Choose "display adapter properity"
choose "list all mode"
[image]

Comment: Have you ever seen a setting that that supports using a defined fraction of the screen?

Comment: This won't work, obviously. And no, there's no solution.